# How can i output corresponding state?

Tags: laravel, model

In the model have a "status",

The "status" have the following state: ["pending", "success", "closed"],

But in the database is digital.

How can I do in the model and number corresponding to the state?

Just like : "0" is success, "1" is "closed"....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use model getters/setters to do this. Here is a rough implementation where you would switch on the value provided, but you might want to pop this into a static array of keys/values to better map between the two.

```
public function getStatusAttribute($value)
{
    switch ($value) {
        case 0:
            return 'Success';

        case 1:
            return 'Closed';
    }
}

public function setStatusAttribute($value)
{
    switch ($value) {
        case 'Success':
            return $this->attributes['status'] = 0;

        case 'Closed':
            return $this->attributes['status'] = 1;

    }
}
```

Edit: for reference, here's how you might go about it using a static array to keep the mapping in a single place.

```
class Model
{
    static $statuses = ['Success', 'Closed'];

    public function getStatusAttribute($value)
    {
        return static::$statuses[$value];
    }

    public function setStatusAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['status'] = array_search($value, static::$statuses);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use const variable.

For example:

```
const STATUS_PERFECT = -1;
const STATUS_WAIT = 0;
const STATUS_PASS = 1;
const STATUS_REJECTED = 2;

public static function ListStatus(){
    return [
        self::STATUS_PERFECT => 'perfect',
        self::STATUS_WAIT  => 'wait',
        self::STATUS_PASS  => 'passing',
        self::STATUS_REJECTED  => 'rejected',
    ];
}
public function getStatusNameAttribute()
{
    $list = self::ListStatus();
    return isset($list[$this->status]) ? $list[$this->status] : $this->status;
}
```